# How to make the height of the mat-form-field-underline 0 in Angular 6+

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular7

I am currently working on angular materials using angular 7. How can we **adjust the height of the mat-form-field-underline** and hence further give a **border around the select box**.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.value">{{type.viewValue}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried giving css using:

```
.link-1 .mat-form-field-underline{ 
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

Here the **link-1** is the parent division. But I am not finding any difference.

Thank you.

Comment: Please look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Basically you need to use `::ng-deep`

```
// You can use /deep/ also
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  // background: red !important;
  height: 0 !important;
}
```

In case, you are bothered about the deprecation warning, you can make the ViewEncapsulation to be None like below

```
    import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'form-example',
      templateUrl: 'form-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['form-example.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })

    .mat-form-field-underline {
     height: 0 !important;
     }
```

Comment: ::ng-deep is no longer supported by angular 6+ versions. I am afraid.

Comment: @Shubham, Yes it would be deprecated until they find a replacement for it. The warning was just to make us aware of it. You can use it for now.

Comment: making use of **"encapsulation"** attribute worked for me, but this brought a new kind of problem.. **The whole division shifted to bottom, seems like they gave a padding to all the child elements** . Efforts are appreciated. Another solution that I came across and which suited me perfectly was using **"Styles"** attribute of the @Component. Have a look at the code below: `styles: [':host/deep/ <here goes the styles inc. {}>']`

Comment: `/deep/` is an alternative to `::ng-deep`. So, one of my solutions worked for you?

Comment: `/deep/` is an alternative to `::ng-deep`. Technically `::ng-deep` is not supported by Angular 6+ versions. But, yes.. you can say, one of your solution worked!!

Comment: `::ng-deep` still works but gonna be deprecated. Can you please upvote and accept my answer so that it helps others

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Basically you need to get it disappeared

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline 
{
   display: none !important;
}
```